# Remove fields in file A that don't contain matches in file B, line by line

Tags: awk, grep

I have a series of paired files, tab separated.

I want to compare line by line each pair and keep in file B only the fields that contain a match with the paired file A.

Example file A:

```
a b
d c
```

Example file B:

```
f>543 h<456 b>536 d>834 v<75345 a>12343
t>4562 c>623 f>3246 h>1345 d<52312
```

Desired output:

```
b>536 a>12343
c>623 d<52312
```

So far I have tried:

1. Convert files B in one-liner files:
   `cat file B | sed 's/\t/\n/g' > file B.mod`
2. Grep one string in file A from file B, print the matching line and the next line, convert the output from 2 line back to single tab separated line:

`cat file B.mod | grep -A1 (string) | awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,NR%2?"\t":"\n" ; }'`

...but this failed since I realized that the matches can be in different order in A and B, as in the example above.

I'd appreciate some help as this goes far beyond my bash skills.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am completely stuck with this one as I don't know how to awk or grep the 2 strings at once in file A from file B, on a line by line basis...sorry...

Comment: There is no wrong or right efforts(as we all are here to learn), whatever you tried please add it in your question to avoid close votes to your question, cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    arr[FNR,$i]
  }
  next
}
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if((FNR,substr($i,1,1)) in arr){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i
    }
  }
  print val
}
'  filea  fileb
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk Program from here.
FNR==NR{                      ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be true when filea is being read.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){         ##Traversing through all fields here.
    arr[FNR,$i]               ##Creating array with index of FNR,current field value here.
  }
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  val=""                      ##Nullify val here.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){         ##Traversing through all fields here.
    if((FNR,substr($i,1,1)) in arr){ ##checking condition if 1st letter of each field with FNR is present in arr then do following.
      val=(val?val OFS:"")$i  ##Creating val which has current $i value in it and keep adding values per line here.
    }
  }
  print val                   ##Printing val here.
}
'  filea  fileb               ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, this was really helpful. I'll study the detailed explanation to learn about the solution. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Mr. Singh: my original files A and B are actually in a slightly different format than the simplified example above and this means that the script works on the example perfectly but not on my files...my bad, very sorry again.
The original format for file A (first 2 lines):
6229232 6227609
8950998 8953406
and original format of file B (first 2 lines):
1c971c76-217c-4bfa-8922-d3a967288a16 chr1:6230629>6229232 chr1:6227609>6227450 chr1:6227517<6230626
11359289-61eb-4673-aa0f-83e9ea2ff669 chr1:8950721<8950998 chr1:8953406<8953539 chr1:8953541>8953441
Can you help?

Comment: @GP, do you want to compare whole value 6229232 with another file? How is the value looking in another file, please comment here.

Comment: Maybe with one line only it will be more clear, apologies.
'File A
6229232 6227609'
'File B
chr1:6230629>6229232 chr1:6227609>6227450 chr1:6227517<6230626'
'Output:
chr1:6230629>6229232 chr1:6227609>6227450'

Comment: @GP, Please try `awk 'FNR==NR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){arr[FNR OFS $i]};next} {val="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){for(key in arr){split(key,temp," ");if(index($i,temp[2])  && FNR==temp[1]){val=(val?val OFS:"")$i}}};print val}'  filea  fileb` once. Also don't change/edit question as of now, because my code works with your shown samples and this is a kind of new requirement :) test this code and let me know here how it goes, if this is too much efforts then we will see if this needs to be discussed in a new thread, cheers.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much again for your time and kindness.